# Poor man's voltage reference

Tags: voltage-reference, accuracy

I want to build a voltage reference based on [LM4040](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4040-n.pdf) (A series 0.1%), the output voltage is switchable with a selector switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvQwuQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming that the op amp have input offset of ~100 uV and resistors are 1% but hand picked to match the values;

- How can I calculate the output error?
- Which parameters affects the accuracy (only resistors error,op amp input offset voltage and temperature)?
- Is there any other downside to this configuration other than lowering the accuracy?

Comment: So you specs are select 1 of 3 inputs with n=1,2,3 x 2.048 V  with 0.1%  resistors and 100uV Vio Op Amp??

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yes the specs are those that I mentioned in the question, though it may vary a bit when building it...

Comment: Look at the temperature coefficients of those resistors (in their datasheet). Higher precision 0.1% resistors aren't that expensive and may have lower tempco.

Comment: @ElectronSurf why not use a DIP switch or rotary switch and make a 8 bit DAC to program it to any precision voltage

Comment: @BrianDrummond The LM4040 is only few cents more expensive than the 0.1% resistors and I need four, buying several LM4040s and putting them in series might cost less than 0.1% resistors...

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Can it be as good as LM4040?

Comment: Why not?  Always decide what you will accept and expect ( write a design spec) not just trial and error

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Anything less than 0.5% is more than enough for me and voltage range 1024, 2048 and 4098 V.

Comment: Note that as an alternative to buying precision resistors or trying to bin for a match there's also the option of buying TCR matched pairs. The important thing is the ratio, not the absolute tolerance. An example: https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/vishay-beyschlag/ACASN1002S1002P1AT/749-1046-1-ND/4741052

Comment: I'd not worry about any of the calculating.  You're not making 100,000 of these - You're only making one.   Replace one of the 1K resistors in each opamp circuit with 470 ohms and a 1k trimpot in series (so you can adjust 500-1500 ohms).  Use your voltmeter to 'dial in' your precision voltages.   A 10-turn trimpot would let you get as precise as you could ever want.   Add a similar trimpot to the unity buffer to fix that ones offset, unless you don't "need" 2.048V and can accept whatever it actually outputs there.  The other 2 voltages can be dialed-in afterwards.  I'd drop a few caps in too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
[**Simulation**](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+0+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+50%0Aw+208+128+208+192+0%0Ag+208+336+208+352+0%0Aa+208+208+320+208+8+15+-15+1000000+1.0239590416383344+1.024+100000%0AO+320+208+368+208+1%0Av+208+336+208+288+0+0+40+2.048+0+0+0.5%0Ar+320+128+320+208+0+1000%0Ar+320+128+368+128+0+1000%0Aw+320+80+320+128+0%0Aw+416+128+416+144+0%0Aw+416+80+416+128+0%0Ag+416+144+416+176+0%0As+368+80+416+80+0+0+false%0As+368+128+416+128+0+0+false%0Ap+208+288+160+288+1+0%0Ap+320+208+320+256+1+0%0Ap+208+192+160+192+1+0%0Ap+320+80+240+80+1+0%0Aw+320+128+208+128+0%0Ar+208+224+208+288+0+1000%0Ar+320+48+368+48+0+1000%0Ar+320+80+368+80+0+1000%0Aw+368+48+368+80+0%0Aw+320+48+320+80+0%0Ax+432+89+558+92+4+16+N%5Cq1,2,3,4%5Csx%5Cs1.024%0Ar+160+224+208+224+0+1000%0Ag+160+224+160+240+0%0A)

Accuracy is only limited by **stack up** of identical resistor tolerance errors which can be matched to 0.1% 50 ppm/'C such as cheap resistor arrays in 10k or 100k range.

2 DIP switches select the feedback ratio to multiply Vref by 1,2,3,4.

Comment: Thanks, how can I get the 1024 V from that configuration? again with a voltage divider?

Comment: oopsss... not paying attention

Comment: corrected ...Rev A

Comment: The problem is that I want to use a rotary selector switch which can only connect one of the switches at a time (sorry I didn't mention that when you was asking for specs), but for getting 4.096 V this needs to have two switches connected. any solution for this?

Comment: edit your question as Rev B.  Change my design to rotary switch selecting open circuit, then resistor values R/1, R/2, R/3. then Vout=1.024 x N = N=1,2,3

Comment: [Like this](http://shorturl.at/zHR68)? it's great, thanks again.

Comment: rotary switch here http://tinyurl.com/y994yjjx  just click on it to advance

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the worst-case output error by adding up all the sources of error and assuming their direction adds.

Initial resistor error, temperature, time drift of resistors (also moisture load life), offset voltage of op-amps, temperature drift of op-amp Vos, op-amp gain vs. loading. Reference error and temperature coefficient. Noise of op-amps, resistors, power supply and reference may also be considered. Voltage coefficient of op-amps and change of reference voltage with supply change. You can buy matched resistor networks so the temperature coefficients and values are matched to each other but they're a bit expensive.

Downside? Power consumption, possibly more noise. Hand picking 1% resistors is not a very good solution compared to buying precision resistors in the first place. If you absolutely must, use matched resistors from the same lot. The calculation won't show the improvement however.

Comment: There's A LOT of parameters to consider! based on **your** experience do you think building a voltage reference like that is practical? any suggestions for a better cheap solution?

Comment: For 0.5% accuracy in an office environment I think it’s no problem, just buy good parts and do a quick calculation.